# Add views dynamically and resize parent ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, view, kotlin

I am trying to create an expandable/collapsable `CardView` (root layout) into which I will add views dynamically to a vertical LinearLayout (parent layout), specifically TextInputLayouts. After adding a view I want to resize the layout animating the process to accommodate the new added view. What I am doing is:

1. Call `removeAllViews()` of the parent
2. Iterate over some objects, initialize child views and added them with `addView()`
3. Calculate the new height as:

   ```
   val previousMeasuredHeight = parentLayout.measuredHeight
   parentLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
   ```
4. Animate the parent layout to the new height as:

   ```
   val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(previousMeasuredHeight, measuredHeight)
   animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
       layoutParams.height = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
       setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
   }
   animator.start()
   ```

I am facing two problems with this:

1. When the error label of the TextInputLayout must be shown it isn't visible because the parent isn't big enough to account for the height taken up by the error label. I guess this has something to do with using `getMeasuredHeight()` instead the correct method to calculate total required height
2. When I add more views and expand the parent layout, only the last added view is visible as it sits on the top of the parent layout

I tried also using a `RecyclerView` but there are also problems such as when an item is added it is not shown, or the parent layout doesn't resize correctly

How do I solve those problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [animateLayoutChanges](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout).

It looks right for what you're trying to achieve and should remove the hassle of calculating the height and animating by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, the problem is that since it is an expandable layout (CardView) that doesn't work since to expand to full height I need to recalculate the real size of the parent with its new children, if not the parent will hide the children as it will never expand to the new heigh

Comment: Sorry about that, I remember it working with any ViewGroup.